# How do I deal with "Your database has already been upgraded" error?

Tags: wordpress, upgrade

While upgrading my civicrm wordpress from 4.6.8 to 4.6.15 i get the error

> Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
>   Your database has already been upgraded to CiviCRM 4.6.8

Does anyone know how to correct this?

I am trying to upgrade CiviCRM on WordPress from 4.6.8 to 4.6.15.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to run the update script before you have downloaded and installed the 4.6.15 version files. Can you double check this?

Comment: Yes make double sure your new civicrm code base has replaces your old one

Answer (score 1):

You can get this error if you download the new codebase but do not (sufficiently) remove the old codebase I believe. renaming the old folder does not necessarily suffice.

Comment: Yes moving civicrm to civicrm.bak and leaving it where it lives will definitively not work