# Update script fails: database already upgraded

Tags: wordpress, upgrade

Trying to update from Wordpress CiviCRM 4.7.11 > 4.7.23.
Update script does not work. Keep getting the same message:

"Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. Your database has already been upgraded to CiviCRM 4.7.11"

I did everything exactly as described: stayed logged in during the process, removed the complete civicrm plugin, installed the new version, removed cache files, cleared browser cache etc.

Does anybody know what the problem is? I know there must be old files somewhere. But where?

Comment: sometimes get this if you have left the old codebase around eg in a renamed directory. have you def. removed the old codebase?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I deal with "Your database has already been upgraded" error?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11350/how-do-i-deal-with-your-database-has-already-been-upgraded-error)

Comment: I checked out all the other comments... Still I get the error. The problem might be that I am updating a test version which I put in a subdirectory of the production version. The production version still contains the old code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oké, thanks for your help. The issue indeed had to do with the test-version in the subdirectory. I am new to CiviCRM and didn't know that you had a seperate settings-file in which you have to configure the database settings. I thought that changing the wordpress settings would be enough. What went wrong is that I changed the wordpress settings, but CiviCRM was still configured for the production database.

Answer (score 1):

Please check related question and answer on this link: [How do I deal with "Your database has already been upgraded" error?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11350/how-do-i-deal-with-your-database-has-already-been-upgraded-error)

Also see documentation on upgrading CiviCRM for Wordpress on the following link: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrading+CiviCRM+for+Wordpress

It is also recommended to use the CiviCRM stackExchange search to check if a similar question has already been asked before posting a new question.

Comment: I checked out all the other questions, and, as I said before, I did everything according to the update manual. The problem might be that I am trying to update a test version which is running in a subdirectory of the production version. Of course the production version still contains the old files... Could that be the case?

Comment: If i understand you well, it means you are running the test version on the same server as production, can you just check your settings file to be sure that the test version is not trying to use the same database with that of production?

Comment: Yes, that's correct: I run the test version on the same server as the production version. I dubble checked the configuration: both versions are defnitly using different databases with different users.